# Disable animated glow effect of tabs with new activity

Tags: google-chrome, settings

How can one disable the animated glowing of tabs with new activity in Google Chrome (version 50) for Ubuntu (running <s>15.04</s> 16.04)?

[image: Tab activity glow]